# Nuxt doesn't recognize .gql files

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I've installed `@nuxtjs/apollo` and `graphql-tag`. I've folder `apollo` with `fragments`, `mutations` and `queries`. But I have problem with run server, after `yarn dev` I'm getting an error: `SyntaxError: Private field '#import' must be declared in an enclosing class`.

For example, one of `apollo/queries` file:

```
#import "../fragments/CartFragment.gql"

query getBasicProfile(
  $acceptLanguage: [Locale!],
  $currency: Currency!,
  $channelId: String,
  $includeChannelIds: [String!],
  $excludeChannelIds: [String!],
  $channelLimit: Int,
  $channelOffset: Int
) {
  me {
    activeCart {
      ...CartFragment
    }
  }
}
```

Why Nuxt doesn't recognize `.gql` files and sees them as `.js` files?

Answer (score 0):

Your only option as of now would be use the gql-tag gql`` or put the fragments inside the same gql file.